# AWS glue copies full data from source to target every time even when there is a bookmark

Tags: aws-glue

I have a glue job generated from the wizard in the aws glue console.  I have not changed the default script on generation of the task. It takes data from a posgres database table (source) and writes to another postgres database(target). I have selected enable bookmark in the ide. Whenever the task runs, it copies the full source database table to the target table even when there is no insert, update or delete in the source. I understand with the bookmark enabled, it should just copy changes in the source from the last run but this is not happening. So if there are 4 rows in the source table, every time the task runs it adds all 4 rows to the target and the row count of target increases by 1. How do I make it process only the chages to the source data from the last run?
Further, how does it bookmark? If a row is modified (update sql statement)between 2 runs, how will it only "update" the correct row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bookmarks only work when copying data between two S3 endpoints. JDBC/ODBC is not supported.

Comment: Thanks @joshua . How are people managing to copy only incremental changes in source to target?

Comment: I marked Joshua's answer as correct because I got a similar response from AWS support.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html This document suggests that: If your crawler runs more than once, perhaps on a schedule, it looks for new or changed files or tables in your data store. The output of the crawler includes new tables found since a previous run.

Comment: @thenaturalist https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html "Currently, job bookmarks are implemented for Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) sources and the Relationalize transform."

Comment: @JoshuaGuttman yup, but the docs state "for S3 *sources*". AWS support confirmed that in fact bookmarks should work for a S3 source and any data sink. It works for me with an S3 source and a JDBC sink. So it seems to me your statement that bookmarks only work between two S3 endpoints is not correct, hence asking for the source.

Comment: @thenaturalist You are stretching the English language. A sink (sic) is not a connection. Bookmarks only work with S3 connections, not JDBC/ODBC connection or any other word that begins with JDBC.

Comment: @JoshuaGuttman apologies, you're right, sink is not the proper term here. My script pulls data from a S3 source and writes to a table via a JDBC configuration. Bookmarks work for me in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC connections are [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html) for bookmarking in AWS Glue jobs. As mentioned in the documentation, there are some preconditions to be satisfied when using with jdbc sources.

```
For JDBC sources, the following rules apply:

 - For each table, AWS Glue uses one or more columns as bookmark keys to determine new and processed data. The bookmark keys combine to form a single compound key.
 - You can specify the columns to use as bookmark keys. If you don't specify bookmark keys, AWS Glue by default uses the primary key as the bookmark key, provided that it is sequentially increasing or decreasing (with no gaps).
 - If user-defined bookmarks keys are used, they must be strictly
   monotonically increasing or decreasing. Gaps are permitted.
```

This means you could have a column `updated_at` in the source table which will serve as bookmark keys. It will be monotonically increasing.

There is further one more important point which is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation but is practiced in all the aws given examples, and is true currently when working with glue job bookmarking.

Always use the [from_catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader-from_catalog) method for datasources, if you wish to use bookmarking. This means the schema should be already present in glue using the crawler or manually.

For JDBC databases you will have to first create a [connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-using.html) and then create a table using a glue crawler (manual creation of JDBC tables is not possible yet)

If you you use [from_options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader-from_options) method for ingesting, sadly glue bookmarking won't work. I learnt this the hard way with S3 data source.

Answer (score 0):

I recently publish a blog on to Build and automate a serverless data lake using an AWS Glue trigger for the Data Catalog and ETL jobs. You can find all code in Cloud-formation template and p

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-and-automate-a-serverless-data-lake-using-an-aws-glue-trigger-for-the-data-catalog-and-etl-jobs/